# Jquery Selector With Variable Not Working

Tags: jquery, variables, selector, attr

So i am trying to get a value of a field using jquery and a variable but for some reason I can't get it to work:

```
    var col = field1;
    var val = $('select[name='+col+']').val();
```

For some reason this code is not working and I am not sure why.  But when I remove the variable it works fine.

```
    var val = $('select[name=field1]').val();
```

This works fine.  How do i pass a variable value into this equation?  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should have `field1` in quotes (you want it to be a string correct?)

```
var col = 'field1'; // now it's a string, and it'll work the way it seems like you intended
```